# Winsock TCP listener stays in LISTENING state after successful closesocket() call

Tags: c++, tcp, listener, winsock

I'm working on an existing DLL where a TCP listening socket is created and is set to immediately rebind to the same socket using SO_REUSEADDR in case of failure. Currently, however, there's an issue in which the listener will stay in LISTENING state, even after a successful call to closesocket(); since it doesn't enter TIME_WAIT, a new listener is created on the same port when the socket is recreated. Clients then fail to connect to the new listener (presumably). SO_LINGER is set to 0 seconds. There are no pending transmissions when the socket is closed. The oldest socket seems to close after about ten seconds without visibly entering another state.

What could keep a listener in LISTENING state after a successful call to closesocket()?

Comment: I take it you mean "rebind to the same address". The answer is it shouldn't stay in listening state after a successful call to closesocket(). I suggest you examine parameters and return values carefully to makes sure you are closing the socket you think you are. The debugger is your friend.

Comment: Yes, rebinding to the same address. Debugging shows that the correct socket handle is being passed to closesocket(), and a data breakpoint on the socket handle isn't triggered before the closesocket() call. The socket is never duplicated. Regardless of the number of listeners in the process shown by ProcExp (one initially, two overlapping during runtime), none of them enter a TIME_WAIT state after a valid call to closesocket().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You closed the wrong socket.
2. You duplicated the handle and forgot to close the duplicate.
3. Somebody else snapped up the port.
4. Your failure code detects failure of the listener when something else is what failed.
5. Your listener is reporting failure when it didn't fail.
6. Your failure mode corrupts the state so closesocket() closes something else.

Comment: 1) The close is validated to be on the correct socket handle.  

2) The handle isn't duplicated anywhere; merely stored in a variable.  

3) The port is validated to only be used by this program.4) Will have to investigate this.

4-7 are issues I've been investigating with no closure, and will continue to look at these.

Comment: A very old question that I forgot to close up - it turns out that the socket handle was, in fact, being duplicated in a CreateProcess() call where handle inheritance was enabled. The socket handle was set as non-inheritable, but this has no effect on WinSock handles.